# Why overriden save() method is bypassed?

Tags: python, django, django-models

In a Django model, I want to avoid doubles so I wrote this:

```
class Points(TimeStampedModel):

    ....

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk:
            super(Points, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        else: # save() is a creation here, not an update
            if Points.objects.filter(benef_card=self.benef_card,
                                     spendable_at=self.spendable_at).exists():
                pass
            else:
                super(Points, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I was very surprised to find this result in my database:

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sevj7v5ujeo94xl/Screenshot%202015-09-20%2019.49.02.png?dl=0]

I suppose there is something wrong with my code, but I'd like to know how these doubles could exist inspite of the protection I wrote in my `save()` method?

Comment: How works the updating? What u can set ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want instead is:

```
class Points(TimeStampedModel):
    # ...
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('benef_card', 'spendable_at')
```

Then you don't need to override `save` -- the uniqueness will be handled by a DB constraint and it is generally the way to go. This approach is better because `save` is not always called (example: bulk operations) so you might get different behavior across your app.

You might also want to check out [`update_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) which just returns an object with attributes you need, creating it if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for this, I will change it for sure. However, even is the save() is the not quickest/cleanest way, it should work too and prevent what happened, right?

Comment: @DavidD. Not everywhere. There are situations where it is done by a manager or `QuerySet` methods, and not all of them use `save`. An example - bulk inserts and updates. But if you use `unique_together` on the other hand, you will have the constraint you want everywhere because it will be enforced by the DB.

Comment: Otherwise than that i don't really see for the moment what could be the issue with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save) instead to check before save.